# Displaying restart dialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

What is the name of this dialog that pops up after software update was performed?

[image]

Comment: MMMMM, Software Update...  finished? Seriously, I don't think it has a name different to`dialog`.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda  No I meant what is the name of this dialog so I can call it programatically, i.e. ProgressMoniotorDialog.

Comment: Oh, I see sorry, I missunderstood you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog is `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.dialogs.ApplyProfileChangesDialog`.

However since this dialog is in an internal package it is not part of the Eclipse API and should not be used - [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). It may be changed at an any time.